# Should I use the same property name for the parent object and child object in prime ng tree table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, primeng

I want to use prime ng tree table to show my data, the object format which is shown in the documentation is as follows :

```js
{
    "data":
    [  
        {  
            "data":{  
                "name":"Documents",
                "size":"75kb",
                "type":"Folder"
            },
            "children":[
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"Work",
                        "size":"55kb",
                        "type":"Folder"
                    },
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Expenses.doc",
                                "size":"30kb",
                                "type":"Document"
                            }
                        },
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Resume.doc",
                                "size":"25kb",
                                "type":"Resume"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"Home",
                        "size":"20kb",
                        "type":"Folder"
                    },
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Invoices",
                                "size":"20kb",
                                "type":"Text"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "data":{  
                "name":"Pictures",
                "size":"150kb",
                "type":"Folder"
            },
            "children":[  
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"barcelona.jpg",
                        "size":"90kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"primeui.png",
                        "size":"30kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"optimus.jpg",
                        "size":"30kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the name of the parent object's property (name) is same as the child object's property name

But the data which I'm getting from the server is different, the names are different in my case,

Take a look at it :

```js
{
    "response": {
        "list": [{
            "id": 1,
            "moduleName": "Pre Admission Form",
            "subModuleList": [{
                "id": 1,
                "moduleId": 1,
                "subModuleName": "AModule1"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "moduleId": 1,
                "subModuleName": "BModule1"
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "moduleId": 1,
                "subModuleName": "BModule12"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "moduleName": "Enrollment",
            "subModuleList": [{
                "id": 4,
                "moduleId": 2,
                "subModuleName": "BModule128"
            }, {
                "id": 5,
                "moduleId": 2,
                "subModuleName": "BModule128"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "moduleName": "Teacher",
            "subModuleList": []
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "moduleName": "Admin Dashboard",
            "subModuleList": []
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "moduleName": "Dashboard",
            "subModuleList": []
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "moduleName": "SMS",
            "subModuleList": []
        }, {
            "id": 7,
            "moduleName": "Diary",
            "subModuleList": []
        }]
    },
    "error": false,
    "errorMsg": null
}
```

DO i need to change my object format, or is there any way to show the tree table with my object ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you get any error when feeding the data ?

Comment: Didnt get any error but the data is not showing up in the table

Comment: Yes, you have to adapt your data to the one of PrimeNG.

Comment: Isn't there any other option?  is it mandatory to use only the prime ng object